# Older GNOME version update in Software Manager

Tags: gnome, updates, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 today and went into the Software Center to see what updates are there. I saw that I have a "gnome-3-38-2004" update, while I'm using GNOME 3.42 which comes with Ubuntu 22.04 . My question is, why is that update in the Software Center? Should I do the update?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the terminal in Ubuntu 22.04 and run `snap list` you will see the following line in the results.

```
gnome-3-38-2004         0+git.891e5bc         112    latest/stable/…  canonical**             -
```

gnome-3-38-2004 is a snap package that was installed as a dependency of other snap packages and it does not interfere with your installed GNOME desktop environment 3.42 at all.

From the results of `snap info gnome-3-38-2004` :

```
This snap includes a GNOME 3.38 stack (the base libraries and desktop  
integration components) and shares it through the content interface.
```

For compatibility with other installed snap packages you might also have the gnome-3-28-1804 snap package installed alongside gnome-3-38-2004. Please note the 1804 and 2004 suffixes that indicate compatibility modes of the gnome-3-28-1804 and gnome-3-38-2004 snap packages.